# Como funciona o tempo de execução do PHP?

Tags: php, runtime, lado-do-servidor

Sempre me interessei em saber por quanto tempo o meu código é executado. O problema é que eu não entendi muito bem como funciona a execução do código PHP. Abaixo estão as perguntas:

No servidor, o código PHP é executado a cada requisição ou ele esta sempre em funcionamento?

Se ele está sempre em funcionamento, ele cria uma nova execução a cada novo visitante?

Se ele não está sempre em funcionamento, há alguma forma de fazer com que ele continue sendo executado? (mesmo após o cliente ter saído do site)

Na internet só encontrei tutoriais sobre a sintaxe da linguagem e como aumentar o tempo de execução (o que não faz sentido se eu não sei como funciona).

Comment: Só para complementar, o PHP não é servidor, o servidor é o apache, nginx, iis, etc.. O servidor que "cria uma nova instância de execução". Em relação ao tempo de execução, é o limite de tempo que o php pode ficar "aberto".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> No servidor, o código PHP é executado a cada requisição ou ele está sempre em funcionamento?

Sim, assim como em qualquer tecnologia, não tem como algo funcionar sem ser executado a cada vez que aquela atividade é desejada.

> Se ele está sempre em funcionamento, ele cria uma nova execução a cada novo visitante?

Quem? O seu código em PHP? Não, ele só e executado quando é necessário, nem teria como ficar executando sem saber o que fazer. Ele cria uma nova instância de execução cada vem que é chamado, mas há otimizações para isso.

> Se ele não está sempre em funcionamento, há alguma forma de fazer com que ele continue sendo executado? (mesmo após o cliente ter saído do site)

Em PHP para web essencialmente não tem como. Até é possível, mas é errado e vai trazer problemas, nem faz sentido fazer isso em PHP para web. Se precisa disso é melhor escolher outra tecnologia.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, você disse que era possível fazer... poderia dizer como? e você poderia citar que outra tecnologia serviria para essa necessidade?

Comment: Mas pq vc quer ficar executando o código a todo momento?

Comment: @Mizukearo para você fazer um código php ficar sendo executado de tempos em tempos sem que alguém crie uma instância, seria usando crontab do linux http://e-tinet.com/linux/agendar-script-php-crontab-no-linux/

Comment: @Mizukearo Como já é algo amplo de se perguntar. Essencialmente qualquer tecnologia que não seja PHP.Esta linguagem é boa para fazer websites simples, qualquer coisa que vá além disso ela não é adequada. As pessoas estão usando onde ela não cabe e estão produzindo aberrações de aplicações.

Comment: @twsouza o objetivo é criar o meu próprio "índice" de algumas páginas web fazendo o php criar requisições para elas, meio que um buscador pessoal... mas pelo visto essa não é a linguagem certa para isso...

Comment: @Mizukearo realmente não é uma boa linguagem, eu recomendo, por opinião própria, ou Golang ou node.js.

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi bem sua duvida, o PHP é executado a cada requisição, quando ele é 'chamado' ele cria uma sessão que seria uma pagina aberta no browser, essa sessão fica ativa até o momento que o browser permanece aberto ( ou vc pode definir o tempo que a sessão fica aberta pela sintaxe do php ) a cada novo visitante vc pode sim fazer com que seja executado uma nova sessão (novamente pela sintaxe do php ) mas vai muito da sua necessidade... 
Da uma olhada nesse site, ajuda pacas pra quem ta iniciando ou no nivel mais intermediario.
http://br.phptherightway.com/#site-header